# How to select data from a column based on data in other columns and transpose it?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have a business scenario where I am trying to select data in a column based on column values in another and later transpose it as a single record.

My Data:

```
MEDIUM     MEDIUM_DETAIL    VALUE
PHN        HOME             7843898789
PHN        WORK             8979909890
PHN        MOBILE           9899876776
EML        PRIMARY          abc@abc.com
EML        ALTERNATE        alt@abc.com
```

The requirement is to display PHN & EML as two columns based on MEDIUM_DETAIL values.

If MEDIUM = 'EML', first check MEDIUM_DETAIL = 'PRIMARY' and use its value. If its NULL, then go on to check 'ALTERNATE' and use its value. If both are null, then print NULL in EML column.

In MEDIUM = 'PHN', first check MEDIUM_DETAIL = 'HOME'. If there is a value, use it. If its NULL, move on to check 'WORK' and 'MOBILE'. Print NULL if all values are null.

So my output as per above example should look like:

```
EML              PHN
abc@abc.com      7843898789
```

I tried using max(decode)...to transpose and even PIVOT but these techniques are need some sort of aggregation and don't give the required result.

Any suggestions on how to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a pivot query:

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN MEDIUM = 'EML' AND MEDIUM_DETAIL = 'PRIMARY'
                      THEN VALUE END),
             MAX(CASE WHEN MEDIUM = 'EML' AND MEDIUM_DETAIL = 'ALTERNATE'
                      THEN VALUE END)) AS EML,
    COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN MEDIUM = 'PHN' AND MEDIUM_DETAIL = 'HOME'
                      THEN VALUE END),
             MAX(CASE WHEN MEDIUM = 'PHN' AND MEDIUM_DETAIL = 'WORK'
                      THEN VALUE END),
             MAX(CASE WHEN MEDIUM = 'PHN' AND MEDIUM_DETAIL = 'MOBILE'
                      THEN VALUE END)) AS PHN
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: this is awesome!

Comment: @ITWeiHan Actually, the other answer, if it works, would probably outperform what I wrote.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen This solution worked well. Thanks for your prompt response. The solution below by hakobot displays duplicate rows and doesn't transpose the data but gets the priority-wise data right.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get it:

```
select MEDIUM, MEDIUM_DETAIL, VALUE ,FIRST_VALUE(value) IGNORE NULLS OVER(partition by MEDIUM order by (case when medium_detail = 'PRIMARY' then 1
                                                                    when medium_detail = 'HOME' then 1 
                                                                    when medium_detail = 'WORK' then 2
                                                                    when medium_detail = 'MOBILE' THEN 3
                                                                    else 4 end) asc) from ttt;
```